# jQuery: previous/next links to tabs don't work!

Tags: jquery, tabs, hyperlink

I added the buttons and set the hrefs for previous and next links to the hrefs from the list items. The links look right in the browser when I click on previous or next, but they go to the same page instead of the specified tab.

I have a dozen of these forms with the tabs and each form has a different number of tabs. The tabs are static (not pulled in with AJAX), and I'd really like to set their hrefs dynamically instead of laying out each one the way I did below. (Each tab has an id that begins with subform.

I looked at this [conversation on select with the tabs plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716038/jquery-ui-tabs-bind-tabs-to-links-on-the-same-page) but wasn't sure how to apply it to my situation. I'm really new at jQuery! The more I know, the more I want to do and it seems like the less I know! I'd appreciate any advice!!

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li class="tabs-selected">
        <a href="#tab_1">Organization</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_2">Leaders</a> </li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Save " /></li>
</ul>

<!-- tab containers -->
<div class="tabs-container" id="tab_1">
    <div class="subform" id="subform1">
        <? include_once ('org.php'); ?>                   
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs-container" id="tab_2">
    <div class="subform" id="subform2">
        <? include_once ('event.php'); ?>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //add previous/next buttons to bottom of each subform
    $(".subform").append('<div id="nav_buttons"><p><a href="" class="previous floatleft">Previous</a> <a href="" class="next floatright">Next</a></p></div>');

    $("#subform1 .previous").hide(); //hide previous button on tab_1 
    $("#subform1 a.next").attr("href","#tab_2");
    $("#subform2 a.previous").attr("href","#tab_1");
    $("#subform2 .next").hide(); //hide next button on last tab

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on Cris Coyier's site, CSS-Tricks. The article, [jQuery UI Tabs with Next/Previous](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/)

Here is the code that worked:

```
$(function() {
    var $tabs = $('.form-tabs').tabs();
    $(".tabs-container").each(function(i){
        var totalSize = $(".tabs-container").size() - 1;
        if (i != totalSize) {
            next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Continue &#187;</a>");
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            prev = i;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Back</a>");
        }
    });
    $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() { 
        $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

What's cool about it is that it finds the number of divs (that provide content for each tab) and then appends the next/previous buttons programmatically, skipping the first previous button and the last next button.

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the selected attribute:

```
$("a.next").click(function() {
    $("#tabNavigation").tabs("select",  
         $("#tabNavigation").tabs("option", "selected") + 1
    );
});


$("a.prev").click(function() {
    $("#tabNavigation").tabs("select", 
        $("#tabNavigation").tabs("option", "selected") - 1
     );
});
```

Comment: I'll try that. How can I find the last tab (subform2 in this case) dynamically so I can hide its next link?

Comment: I don't think you need to use the tabs plugin to accomplish that.  All you have to do is find the link in question and hide it.  This could do the trick:  `$('#' + $('#tabNavigation a:last').attr('href') + ' a.next').hide();`

Comment: Regarding your comment, the previous link in the first subform and the next link in the last subform do not hide. I thought it might be that extra # since the href already has a # (#tab_8, for example) and changed that to the empty string. It still didn't work.

Comment: Regarding your code with the selected attribute, could the problem be that I've added the previous/next links dynamically?